# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick when trying JSONParser

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, illegalstateexception

I am not a developer.  Just started learning android a few weeks ago.  I am running into a

*"java.lang.IllegalStateException Could not execute method for android:onClick"*
error. I have read through similar issues and tried different solutions I read here but still cannot resolve it.  Seems like it is crashing right when I try *JSONParser parser = new JSONParser()* - I think.  But I know the *'clickme'* triggers when i click the button on the android app.

I would appreciate if someone more experienced can help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Thread Policy 
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    }

    public void clickme (View view) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("assets/StockDB.json"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            JSONArray stockInfo = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Watchlist");

            for (Object c : stockInfo)
            {

                JSONObject f = (JSONObject) c;
                String m = (String) f.get("Company");
                String t = (String) f.get("Ticker");

                System.out.println(m);
                System.out.println(t);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    }   
}
```

Logcat:

03-03 17:02:12.415: D/AndroidRuntime(22035): Shutting down VM
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035): Process: com.example.stockiodebug, PID: 22035
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4740)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10815)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4735)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    ... 10 more
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/json/simple/parser/JSONParser;
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at com.example.stockiodebug.MainActivity.clickme(MainActivity.java:33)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    ... 12 more
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.stockiodebug-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.stockiodebug-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    ... 13 more
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):        ... 14 more
03-03 17:02:12.425: E/AndroidRuntime(22035):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Comment: Go to the "libs" directory of your project and make sure that _org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser_ related _.jar_ is placed there. Such an error would arise when _JVM_ cannot find required class in the _classpath_.

Comment: I have added an answer below. If my suggestion of adding .jar to libs folder solved your issue then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the "libs" directory of your project and make sure that org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser related .jar is placed there. Such an error would arise when JVM cannot find required class in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This error is come because  it throws `ClassNotFoundException`, producing an `IllegalStateException` in the exception chain.

In your code `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser` is not found.

Try with implementing JsonParser library.

Comment: Thank you.  I was under the impression that in Eclipse, by Right Clicking on Project Name ->Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add External JARs took care of adding the org.json to my project.  I didn't know I had to also copy it to the libs folder.